# Using a single connectionstring for local and in docker (Database Access)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to have an API with the same connectionstring for running locally and in Docker? This would enable me to debug the code while accessing the database in Docker, and to run everything in Docker without **any additional configuration**

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Host=postgres-db;Port=5432;Database=database;Username=postgres;Password=postgres;Include Error Detail=true"
  },
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  example-api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
    container_name: example-api
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Api/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db

  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:14.1
    container_name: postgres-db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=database
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - 5100:5432
```

Comment: This is possibly an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We generally deal with this through environment variables. So, in docker you'd have one set of environment variables, and in your host machine, another, each pointing to the correct destination.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, this how I do it: 1. Make the application read the connection information from environment variables. 2: setup the environment variable for the application service (`example-api`) in docker-compose using the Docker addresses. 3: setup environment variables for the application when running through the host machine (a `.env` file that's not copied into the container, or even vscode's `"env"` key in the run configuration).

Comment: The other thing I generally do in a similar situation is, if the environment variable isn't set, use the value a developer running locally would use (`localhost:5100` in this example).  In a real deployment situation, the deployment mechanics checked into source control will always set the environment variable.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Following this path, I just created a new appsettings file called 'appsettings.Test.json' using environment variables in Docker Compose to understand the configurations. If someone knows how to do that without environment variables, please leave a comment